# Can't get the fancybox-function to work using html/php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, fancybox

I have searched for an answer over and over again, but I can't seem to figure this one out. I want to simply use fancybox to show an image.

This is the first time I use fancybox, so probably someone experienced will notice the problem within seconds.

I've followed the steps given at http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/.

This is the code I have in my head.php file:

```
    <!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

<!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
```

This is copied from the given website. 
I'm using the exact samen folder-name "fancybox", so I think that can't be the problem.
In my code where I want to load an image, this is what I have:

```
echo'<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="img/products/'.$row['bestandsnaam'].'"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="img/products/'.$row['bestandsnaam'].'" alt=""></a>';
```

After loading this page, I have this code (also copied from the given website):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

Yet when I click this image, it won't open in fancybox, but it opens in a new tab instead only showing the image without any fancy styling.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Are you sure all the files are where you point to? In the console, are there any warnings?

Comment: This `/fancybox/` means that you have created (and placed the fancybox files at) this folder at the root level. Make sure that is correct

Comment: Thanks for the reactions.. sorry for late reply ;).
Yes, I'm pointing to the right directions. I now found out that I have an error, I'll post that error as an image as a reply to DelightedD0D's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most assuredly due to your files not being in the place your links are pointing to.And you should be seeing several errors in the console related to this.

[Here is a test page using your code with the urls modified to match the folder layout shown in the image below](http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/fancybox/fancy.php). As you can see it does work. Therefore, your issue must be due to your urls being incorrect or the files themselves being missing.

**This is the code from the test page:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

   <!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

<!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $row['bestandsnaam'] = 'images.jpg';
    echo'<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="img/products/'.$row['bestandsnaam'].'"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="img/products/'.$row['bestandsnaam'].'" alt=""></a>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Folder layout:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, and sorry for the very late reply. Deadlines from my studies were killing me for two weeks ;). 
I just looked it up, but I can't find where it goes wrong.. I'll go through every single file again, if I can't find the problem again, I'll post some more detailed information about my folder layout etc. Thanks again!

Comment: I guess all my code is right. I wasn't familiar with the errors in the console, now I am :). And I found out that I have an error:

https://imageshack.us/i/exAkm6LNp

I'm in a train now with some buggy internet connection, so I hope the upload worked. I don't have the time to find out exactly what this error means, but I will try when I have the time. Thanks again for your help :).

Comment: I've resolved this issue. I don't even know why, but in my footer, there was this line:
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
I removed that line and the fancybox worked just fine. I don't know why this worked, but it worked. If anyone could explain to me, why this helped, that would be amazing.

Thanks for your effort!

Comment: @Kenny Looks like you were loading jQuery twice which was causing conflicts.